# Arrange numbers to a 6 point star

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

[image]

Arrange the numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12, and 16) to replace the letters, so every 3 vertices which form a triangle have equal sums.

Comment: Little typo: there's two "B"s in that picture

Comment: There ara 8 triangles, all must have equal sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "**B**" in the upper right of the diagram is supposed to be an **E**,

> A=1 B=4 C=12 D=5 E=9 F=16 G=7 H=3 I=2 J=11 K=8 L=6 sums=21

is one solution.  There are several.

Keeping the "**B**" as a **B**

> there are no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to computing all the sums by hand is using a constraint solving system like SWI-Prolog with clpfd. The program looks similar to the task at hand:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

node(N) :- N in 1..16, N #\= 10, N #\= 13, N #\= 14, N #\= 15.

triangle(Nodes) :-
  Nodes = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L],
  node(A), node(B), node(C),
  node(D), node(E), node(F),
  node(G), node(H), node(I),
  node(J), node(K), node(L),
  all_distinct(Nodes),

  A + B + F #= Sum,
  B + C + D #= Sum,
  D + E + G #= Sum,
  G + L + K #= Sum,
  K + J + I #= Sum,
  I + H + F #= Sum,
  A + E + J #= Sum,
  C + H + L #= Sum,

  F #< B,   % Prevent symmetrical solutions by requiring F
  F #< D,   % to be the smallest inside, and B < I.
  F #< G,
  F #< K,
  F #< I,
  B #< I.
```

Running this program produces this:

> `?- triangle(Solution), label(Solution).
>  Solution = [11, 8, 6, 7, 9, 2, 5, 3, 16, 1, 4, 12] ;
>  Solution = [11, 9, 5, 7, 8, 1, 6, 4, 16, 2, 3, 12] ;
>  Solution = [16, 3, 6, 12, 4, 2, 5, 8, 11, 1, 9, 7] ;
>  Solution = [16, 4, 5, 12, 3, 1, 6, 9, 11, 2, 8, 7] ;`

Answer (score 1):

The set of equations is:

- `F + A + B = sum`
- `B + C + D = sum`
- `D + E + G = sum`
- `G + L + K = sum`
- `K + J + I = sum`
- `I + H + F = sum`
- `A + B + J = sum`
- `C + L + H = sum`

Summed up, this is:

`2 * (A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H + I + J + K + L) = 8 * sum`

Luckily, we already know this sum, which is `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 11 + 12 + 16` (in any order).

So the sum of each triangle must be

> 21.

Since this sum is a whole number, there *might* be a solution. Knowing the sum makes it easier to just try some combinations and quickly reject those tries that have a wrong sum in one of the triangles. Using a small Python program reveals that only the following triangles are possible:

> `nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 16]
>  for a in nums:
>    for b in nums:
>      for c in nums:
>        if a < b and b < c and a + b + c == 21:
>          print(a,b,c)`
>
>
>  And this is the result:
>
>  
>  `(1, 4, 16)
>  (2, 3, 16)
>  (1, 8, 12)
>  (2, 7, 12)
>  (3, 6, 12)
>  (4, 5, 12)
>  (1, 9, 11)
>  (2, 8, 11)
>  (3, 7, 11)
>  (4, 6, 11)
>  (4, 8, 9)
>  (5, 7, 9)
>  (6, 7, 8)`

Each of the numbers must be part of 2 triangles.

The 16 can be either on an inside node or on an outside one.
Only these two can be distinguished topologically.
The rest is laborious work, trying out all possibilities.

> `16 inside
>    1+4+16, 1 inside
>      2+3+16, 2 inside
>        1+8+12, 8 inside
>          3+6+12 must be all-outside
>          no triangle fits 6+x+y (-)
>        1+8+12, 12 inside
>          no triangle fits 3+8+x (-)
>        1+9+11, 9 inside
>          3+7+11 must be all-outside
>          6+7+8, 6 near 9
>            no triangle fits 6+9+x (-)
>          6+7+8, 8 near 9
>            no triangle fits 8+9+x (-)
>        1+9+11, 11 inside
>          no triangle fits 3+9+x (-)
>      2+3+16, 3 inside
>        1+8+12, 8 inside
>          2+7+12 must be all-outside
>          5+7+9, 5 near 8
>            no triangle fits 5+8+x (-)
>          5+7+9, 9 near 8
>            no triangle fits 8+9+x (-)
>        1+8+12, 12 inside
>          2+8+11 must be all-outside
>          no triangle fits 11+x+y (-)
>        1+9+11, 9 inside
>          2+8+11 must be all-outside
>          6+7+8, 6 near 9
>            no triangle fits 6+9+x (-)
>          6+7+8, 7 near 9
>            5+7+9 is forced
>            4+5+12 is forced (+++ solution)
>        1+9+11, 11 inside
>          no triangle fits 2+9+x (-)
>    1+4+16, 4 inside
>      2+3+16, 2 inside
>        1+8+12, 8 near 2
>          2+8+11 is forced
>          no triangle fits 11+x+y (-)
>        1+8+12, 12 near 2
>          2+7+12 is forced
>          5+7+9, 5 inside
>            no triangle fits 3+12+x (-)
>          5+7+9, 9 inside
>            no triangle fits 8+9+x (-)
>          6+7+8, 6 inside
>            no triangle fits 6+8+x (-)
>          6+7+8, 8 inside
>            no triangle fits 8+8+x (-)
>        (here I forgot to check 2+8+11, which leads to another solution)
>      2+3+16, 3 inside
>        3+6+12, 6 inside
>          1+8+12 is forced
>          no triangle fits 8+x+y (-)
>        3+6+12, 12 inside
>          no triangle fits 12+x+y (-)
>  16 outside
>    1+4+16 all-outside
>      2+3+16, 2 near 1
>        2+7+12, 7 inside
>          no triangle fits 1+7+x (-)
>        2+7+12, 12 inside
>          1+8+12 is forced
>          no triangle fits 8+x+y (-)
>        2+8+11, 8 inside
>          1+8+12 is forced
>          no triangle fits 12+x+y (-)
>        2+8+11, 11 inside
>          1+9+11 is forced
>          5+7+9, 5 inside
>            6+7+8 is forced
>            3+6+12 is forced (+++ solution)
>          5+7+9, 7 inside
>            no triangle fits 4+7+x (-)
>      2+3+16, 3 near 1
>        3+6+12, 6 inside
>          no triangle fits 1+6+x (-)
>        3+6+12, 12 inside
>          1+8+12 is forced
>          no triangle fits 8+x+y (-)
>    2+3+16 all-outside
>      1+4+16, 1 near 2
>        1+8+12, 8 inside
>          2+8+11 is forced
>          no triangle fits 11+x+y (-)
>        1+8+12, 12 inside
>          2+7+12 is forced
>          5+7+9, 5 inside
>            no triangle fits 3+5+x (-)
>          5+7+9, 9 inside
>            no triangle fits 3+9+x (-)
>        1+9+11, 9 inside
>          no triangle fits 2+9+x (-)
>        1+9+11, 11 inside
>          2+8+11 is forced
>          6+7+8, 6 inside
>            3+6+12 is forced
>            4+12+5 is forced (+++ solution)
>          6+7+8, 7 inside
>            no triangle fits 6+9+x (-)
>      1+4+16, 4 near 2
>        1+8+12, 8 inside
>          no triangle fits 3+8+x (-)
>        1+8+12, 12 inside
>          3+6+12 is forced
>          no triangle fits 6+x+y (-)
>        1+9+11, 9 inside
>          no triangle fits 3+9+x (-)
>        1+9+11, 11 inside
>          3+7+11 is forced
>          6+7+8, 6 inside
>            no triangle fits 2+6+x (-)
>          6+7+8, 8 inside
>            no triangle fits 6+9+x (-)`

So after all, there are <s>three</s>four topologically unique solutions.